# Is this the fastest way to do Multi processing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am using this

```
def processImage(i):
      # Load image
      # Predict on the image using Machine learning model that uses GPU
      # Print the result

p=mp.Pool(3) #Define Number of Process to Use
p.map(processImage,range(len(filesToProcess))) # Call the Download Image funciton
p.close() #Close the multi threads
p.join()
```

I wonder, how can I speed this up? This multi process code is not 3x faster than one process code. I know there will be some overhead, but how can  I reduce those?

Comment: While it doesn't answer your question, I find this to be easier to use than `multiprocessing`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example You might want to give it a go.

Comment: @TomWojcik - maybe ProcessPoolExecutor fot cpu intensive tasks.

Comment: `...is not 3x faster...` - how much faster is it? Is it slower?

Comment: It's like 1.8x faster.

Comment: However, It totally depends on the code inside processImage. But it should not matter, what's inside processImage right? I already mentioned, that it first load some image, predict using a machine learning model that uses GPU and print the result.

Comment: @wwii can you provide an example of using ProcessPoolExecutor? I copy/pasted the example code on python.org and getting this error `BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.`

Comment: `...should not matter, what's inside processImage…` - depends on where the bottlenecks are, have you profiled the function to see if it can be improved? Return results instead of printing? Have the processes work on multiple files and offload the file load to a thread? How many other strategies did you employ other than throwing cores at it>

Comment: Sir, I am new to programming, really don't know much stuff. I tried to google fastest way, but not found any good guide (updated what works in 2019). Let me google what is profiled, and other things and get back to you

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: @johndoe **of course it depends on what is inside `processImage`**. Parallelism isn't magic you sprinkle onto code to make it faster. It is oftentimes just as likely to slow down your code.

Comment: ohh, in that case can you just name down few multiprocessing methods that I can try? I can test them all.